# How to fix name not defined error in the provided code below?

Tags: python

I'm trying to inherit all the parent class' attributes to my child class. However, I don't want to keep them all as parameters because it seems redundant.

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, type, diet, sick, hunger, energy, location):
        self.type = type
        self.diet = diet
        self.sick = sick
        self.hunger = hunger
        self.energy = energy
        self.location = location

class Tiger(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(type, diet, location, hunger, energy, sick)
        self.type = 'tiger'
        self.diet = diet
        self.location = 'land'
        self.hunger = 100
        self.energy = 100
        self.sick = False



tiger = Tiger()
print(tiger)
```

But I run into this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zoosimulation.py", line 22, in <module>
    tiger = Tiger()
  File "zoosimulation.py", line 12, in __init__
    super().__init__(type, diet, location, hunger, energy, sick)
NameError: name 'diet' is not defined
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn't make sense. Diet etc. *aren't* defined (you lucked out on `type` because it's a built-in function). Did you mean e.g. `super.__init__('tiger', ...)`, and if so should that be an instance rather than a subclass?

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer by clicking on the check mark next to it. That will remove your question from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to *pass* the values to the parent constructor:

```
class Tiger(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('tiger', 'meat', False, 100, 100, 'land')
```

Two important things here:

1. I'm not sure where you got `diet` from, but I made up a reasonable placeholder. A very important part of not getting `NameError` is making sure all your variables are defined before you use them.
2. The order that you pass things to the constructor in is very important. The order used in the call to `super` must be the same order that `Animal.__init__` defines, since that is the function that is being called.

Alternatively, you can pass in the diet:

```
class Tiger(Animal):
    def __init__(self, diet):
        super().__init__('tiger', diet, 'land', 100, 100, False)
```

Another way is to bypass the parent initializer, as long as you know what you are doing:

```
class Tiger(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = 'tiger'
        self.diet = 'meat'
        self.location = 'land'
        self.hunger = 100
        self.energy = 100
        self.sick = False
```

Comment: I've just spotted that the parameters for `Animal.__init__` are in a different order, and have edited my answer accordingly. You may want to do the same with yours. Like you, I was copying the order from where the OP had attempted to call it, rather than the different order where they had actually defined it.

Comment: @alaniwi. Thanks for the catch. I added some emphasis for that.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I'll get to correcting it :)

Answer (score 1):

It would work if you make `diet` an `__init__` parameter and set some suitable variables before calling `Animal.__init__`.  No need to set the instance properties because `Animal.__init__` will do that for you.

```
class Tiger(Animal):
    def __init__(self, diet):
        type_ = 'tiger'
        location = 'land'
        hunger = 100
        energy = 100
        sick = False
        super().__init__(type_, diet, sick, hunger, energy, location)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the asterisk operator in order to save you some of the code and make inheritance more convenient:

```
class Tiger(Animal):
    def __init__(self, *par):
        super().__init__(*par)
```

Additionally, this gives you the possibility to just add further arguments to your subclass, for example:

```
class Tiger(Animal):
    def __init__(self, height, *par):
        super().__init__(*par)
        self.height = height
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass your parameters into the constructor:

```py
class Tiger(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('tiger', 'meat', False, 100, 100, 'land')
```

I guessed the diet should be meat.

Comment: You should fix those smart quotes.